# Create vertical submenu for horizontal menu

Tags: html, css, submenu

I've spent more time trying to do this than I'm willing to admit.  I just can't seem to figure this out.  I'm trying to build something which I believe is very simple.  I've got a horizontal menu.  And I want to have the submenu be vertical when someone hovers over a given link.

This is what I've got right now at [RetirePhoenixArizona.com](http://retirephoenizarizona.com/):

**HTML**

```
<nav class="secondary-navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="secondary-menu">
                <li><a href="google.com">Link 1</a>
                        <ul class="secondary-submenu">
                            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="facebook.com">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="google.com">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="facebook.com">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#secondary-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

#secondary-menu li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

#secondary-menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#secondary-menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

#secondary-menu ul {
  display: none;
}

#secondary-menu li:hover > ul {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  width: 200px;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}

#secondary-menu li:hover > ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the float on the li of the submenu

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  display: block;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

ul ul {
  display: none;
}

li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40px;
  right: 0;
}

li:hover > ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: ...and the width too probably.

Comment: Still no dice with that.  Here's the latest.  (I updated the code)

Comment: When I hover over the main menu, the submenu appears but once I move my mouse toward it, it disappears again.  So I can't actually choose anything on the submenu.

Comment: For the CSS solution there mustn't be a space between the main entries and the sub entries... If the mouse goes from one to the other while at any moment being above on of them it should be allright.

Answer (score 0):

I Just do a responsive horizontal Menu ... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40084673/3378770)
If you don't need responsive remove all concern container , bar1,bar2,bar3, icon, change, @media screen and (max-width:680px)  and the javascript