# Horizontal Responsive Menu with submenu into vertical

Tags: javascript, css, menu, submenu

I use since severals years a simple horizontal css menu with submenu.
I try to modify it to tranform in responsive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
 ul{padding-left: 0;}

    .container {
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
        width: 35px;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: #BDF1A5;
        margin: 6px 0;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    .change .bar1 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    }

    .change .bar2 {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .change .bar3 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    }

    .menu_deroulant {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #534D4D;
        font-size: 0;
    }

        .menu_deroulant li {
            float:left;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .menu_deroulant a {
            font-family: Candara;
            font-size: medium;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: block;
            width: 180px;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #534D4D;
        }

            .menu_deroulant a:visited, .menu_deroulant a:link {
                color: #BDF1A5;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .menu_deroulant a:hover {
                background-color: #897E7E;
            }

        .menu_deroulant li.icon {
            display: none;
        }

        .menu_deroulant ul {
            left: -999em;
            position: absolute;
        }

        .menu_deroulant li:hover > ul {
            left: 0;
        }

    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
        ul.menu_deroulant li:not(:first-child) {
            display: none;
        }

        ul.menu_deroulant li.icon {
            float: right;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
        ul.menu_deroulant.responsive {
            position: relative;
        }

            ul.menu_deroulant.responsive li.icon {
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
            }

            ul.menu_deroulant.responsive li {
                float: none;
                display: inline;
            }

                ul.menu_deroulant.responsive li a {
                    display: block;
                    text-align: left;
                }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="menu_deroulant" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Réalisations</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/Realisations-Site-Web.aspx" title="Réalisations de Site Web">Réalisations de Site Internet</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Realisations-Intranet.aspx" title="Réalisations d'Intranet et de développement">Réalisations d'Intranet</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li class="icon">
        <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    function myFunction(y) {
        y.classList.toggle("change");
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "menu_deroulant") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "menu_deroulant";
        }
    }
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

But I've a problem in vertical mode with my submenu. It's not in good place.
I search in w3schools.com and Google but don't find what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I change my basic horizontal Menu. And it's give that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .container {
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
        width: 35px;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: #BDF1A5;
        margin: 6px 0;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }

    .change .bar1 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    }

    .change .bar2 {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .change .bar3 {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #534D4D;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

        li a {
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            width: 180px;
        }

            li a:hover {
                background-color: red;
            }

        li.dropdown {
            display: inline-block;
        }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }

            .dropdown-content a:hover {
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
            }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }

    li.icon {
        display: none;
    }
    /*li:not(:first-child)*/
    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
        ul.menu_deroulant li {
            display: none;
        }

            ul.menu_deroulant li.icon {
                float: right;
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: #534D4D;
                padding: 5px;
            }

        ul.menu_deroulant.responsive {
            position: relative;
        }

            ul.menu_deroulant.responsive li.icon {
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
            }

            ul.menu_deroulant.responsive li {
                float: none;
                display: inline;
            }

                ul.menu_deroulant.responsive li a {
                    display: block;
                    text-align: left;
                }

        .dropdown-content {
            position: absolute;
            left: 208px;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="menu_deroulant" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Réalisations</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="icon">
        <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    function myFunction(y) {
        y.classList.toggle("change");
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "menu_deroulant") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "menu_deroulant";
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And it's good. I let you my code to help you :-)